# What's the correct value to base the maximum number of CPU's to sched_setaffinity to?

Tags: cpu, proc, process-management

I have some confusion as to what's the correct value to use for the number of CPU's I can use to make a `CPU_SET` for a `sched_setaffinity` call on my system.

My `/proc/cpuinfo` file:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 37
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x2
cpu MHz     : 1199.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5056.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 37
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x2
cpu MHz     : 1199.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5056.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 37
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x2
cpu MHz     : 1199.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5056.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 37
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x2
cpu MHz     : 1199.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5056.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

In this file there are `processor` lines numbered 0-3, for "physical" processors (4 processors total). I can get this value from `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)` but, there is also a line for `cpu cores` and each processor has 2. I believe this represents the "logical" processors or hyperthreading that is accounted for. Should I be using only the "physical" value or can I use the "logical" count?

I'm not clear on this because if I go to `/proc/PID/status` theres the line `Cpus_allowed_list` and that can range from 0-7 (8 processors total) but, I also wrote a script to call `taskset -c -p PID` for every "PID" running and this shows every process of having an affinity list of 0-3 max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CPU is a dual core CPU with hyperthreading [Intel® Core™ i5-460M Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/50179/Intel-Core-i5-460M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz)

- This means you have 2 cores and they are physical CPU's.
- You have also hyperthreading and so you have 4 logical CPU's.

`taskset` was designed because the balancing of tasks in a multicore CPU was a performance lost. The tasks did normally not use hyperthreading and CPU's had only separate caches. You have a hyperthreading CPU so you'll never know which physical CPU is in use and the balancing of tasks normally does not result in a performance lost because they use the same cache. Intel's smart(unified) cache seems to make taskset obsolete. However using `taskset` in a NUMA System makes still sense.

A benchmark can answer if you can increase performance using `taskset` here.

Comment: I had been getting things mixed here mainly because of "cpus_allowed_list" is showing 0-7(8 cores) which I took to misinterpret how to read the correct number in `/proc/cpuinfo`